# Filtering on Cisco Prime API v3

Tags: cisco

I'm trying to use cisco prime v3 to and get data AccessPointDetails with filter on CDP Neighbor.

I tried https://xxx/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails?cdpNeighbors.cdpNeighbor="X.X.X.X" but it gives error

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<errorDocument>
    <httpResponseCode>400</httpResponseCode>
    <httpMethod>GET</httpMethod>
    <message>Unexpected query parameters [cdpNeighbors.cdpNeighbor].-PRS-115</message>
    <id>presentation.PRS-115</id>
    <uriPath>data/AccessPointDetails</uriPath>
    <queryParams>{cdpNeighbors.cdpNeighbor=[&amp;quot;X.X.X.X&amp;quot;]}</queryParams>
</errorDocument>
```

and in documentation it says to use ../webacs/api/v3/data/WlanProfiles?hotspotGeneral.heSsid="000000000000" when to filter on properties

Response from https://xxx/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/7387381 looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<queryResponse type="AccessPointDetails" responseType="getEntity" requestUrl="https://xxx/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/7387381" rootUrl="https://xxx/webacs/api/v3/data">
    <entity dtoType="accessPointDetailsDTO" type="AccessPointDetails" url="https://xxx/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails/7387381">
        <accessPointDetailsDTO displayName="7387381" id="7387381">
            <adminStatus>ENABLE</adminStatus>
            <apType>AP2700I</apType>
            <cdpNeighbors>
                <cdpNeighbor>
                    <capabilities>Switch IGMP </capabilities>
                    <duplex>Full Duplex</duplex>
                    <interfaceSpeed>1Gbps</interfaceSpeed>
                    <localPort>2</localPort>
                    <neighborIpAddress>X.X.X.X</neighborIpAddress>
                    <neighborName>XXX</neighborName>
                    <neighborPort>GigabitEthernet1/0/25</neighborPort>
                    <platform>cisco WS-C2960X-48FPS-L</platform>
                </cdpNeighbor>
            </cdpNeighbors>
            <clientCount>0</clientCount>
            <clientCount_2_4GHz>0</clientCount_2_4GHz>
            <clientCount_5GHz>0</clientCount_5GHz>
            <ethernetMac>AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF</ethernetMac>
            <ipAddress>X.X.X.X</ipAddress>
            <locationHierarchy>XX &gt; XX &gt; XX</locationHierarchy>
            <macAddress>AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF</macAddress>
            <mapLocation>XX - XX</mapLocation>
            <model>AIR-CAP2702I-E-K9</model>
            <name>XXXX</name>
            <reachabilityStatus>REACHABLE</reachabilityStatus>
            <serialNumber>XXX</serialNumber>
            <softwareVersion>8.5.124.34</softwareVersion>
            <status>CLEARED</status>
            <type>UnifiedAp</type>
            <unifiedApInfo>
                <apCertType>1</apCertType>
                <apGroupName>XX</apGroupName>
                <apMode>0</apMode>
                <apStaticEnabled>0</apStaticEnabled>
                <bootVersion>15.2.4.5</bootVersion>
                <capwapJoinTakenTime>1700</capwapJoinTakenTime>
                <capwapUpTime>809211472</capwapUpTime>
                <controllerIpAddress>X.X.X.X</controllerIpAddress>
                <controllerName>XXXX</controllerName>
                <contryCode>SE</contryCode>
                <encryptionEnabled>false</encryptionEnabled>
                <flexConnectMode>false</flexConnectMode>
                <iosVersion>15.3(20180323:033237)$</iosVersion>
                <linkLatencyEnabled>false</linkLatencyEnabled>
                <poeStatus>4</poeStatus>
                <poeStatusEnum>NORMAL</poeStatusEnum>
                <portNumber>8</portNumber>
                <powerInjectorState>1</powerInjectorState>
                <preStandardState>0</preStandardState>
                <primaryMwar>XXX</primaryMwar>
                <rogueDetectionEnabled>true</rogueDetectionEnabled>
                <secondaryMwar>XXX</secondaryMwar>
                <sshEnabled>true</sshEnabled>
                <statisticsTimer>180</statisticsTimer>
                <telnetEnabled>false</telnetEnabled>
                <WIPSEnabled>0</WIPSEnabled>
                <wlanProfiles>
                    <wlanProfile>
                        <broadcastSsidEnabled>true</broadcastSsidEnabled>
                        <profileName>XX</profileName>
                        <ssid>XX</ssid>
                    </wlanProfile>
                    <wlanProfile>
                        <broadcastSsidEnabled>true</broadcastSsidEnabled>
                        <profileName>XX</profileName>
                        <ssid>XX</ssid>
                    </wlanProfile>
                </wlanProfiles>
                <wlanVlanMappings></wlanVlanMappings>
            </unifiedApInfo>
            <upTime>809222772</upTime>
        </accessPointDetailsDTO>
    </entity>
</queryResponse>
```

Anyone who has succeded with this?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It's is as simply as 
https://xxx/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails?.full=true&cdpNeighbor.neighborIpAddress="X.X.X.X"